# Why does combiner doesn't invoke in stream.reduce although result is right

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I have wrote following code example for calculate total string length in the stream:

```
Integer reduce = Stream.of("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
            .reduce(0, (result, s) -> {
                System.out.println("#accumulator# " + s);
                return result + s.length();
            }, (integer, integer2) -> {
                System.out
                        .println("#combiner#" + "integer: " + integer + "integer2:" + integer2);
                return integer + integer2;
            });
    System.out.println(reduce);
```

I see following output:

```
#accumulator# AAA
#accumulator# BBB
#accumulator# CCC
9
```

As you can see I got right result but combiner is never invokes.

Why? how this works in details?

Please, explain concept.

Answer (score 3):

The combiner parameter in [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) is actually invoked only in the case of a parallel Stream. This is because when a stream executes in parallel, Java partitions the stream into multiple substreams. Aggregate operations iterate over and process these substreams in parallel and then combine the results.

Change your code to use a parallel Stream by invoking `parallel()` and you will see that the combiner gets invoked.

In the Javadoc of this method, you can see that `combiner` is not present in the equivalent code:

> This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> U result = identity;
> for (T element : this stream)
>     result = accumulator.apply(result, element)
> return result;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: The combiner is called for **parallel Streams**.

The combining function is called when the `Spliterator` is `split()` for processing in two different `Thread`s and the the results need to be merged.  As your `Stream` is not `parallel` this functionality is not required.

Incidentally, your code is better written as:

```
final int total = Stream.of("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
                        .mapToInt(String::length)
                        .sum();
```

Comment: it look very hard. I cannot understand concept

Comment: in paralel case invokes both: combiner and accumulator

Comment: @gstackoverflow is there a question there or are you just making a statement?

Comment: @gstackoverflow what is a question?

Comment: How does it work in general ? meaning of this design ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow I have explained the basics. And the general case is too broad for this forum - for that you will have to work through some tutorials.